# Android app crashes while loading notification messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

1. Open app and make sure its having network connection ON. (Ohh yes it will show you alert otherwise and prompt you to make internet connection ON).
2. Now click on the Feed icon and it will load all Inbox messages.
   [image]
3. Turn off the Data connection
4. Again click on the Message icon and try to pull-down the messages list to refresh/load.
5. It will show you below Force close dialog.

   [image]

**Below are the configuration/device detail with which I am testing app:**

- MicroMax A110 with Android 4.1.1
- 1.48 GB Internal storage
- 8 GB External SD-card
- 1 GB Internal SD-card

Today morning I have received update of app, updated it and already using updated one.

Comment: Why feature-request???

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I didn't know earlier but thought its request to resolve bug so included feature-request tag. Thanks for editing.

Comment: Reproducible - Android Nexus 4.  It seems that it doesn't like the possibility that the network could go missing.

Comment: So what you are saying, @Makoto, is that the Android app is channeling its user's insecurities?

Comment: Reproducible in Android 4.2.1

Comment: Thanks Gowtham for confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular one will be fixed in 0.1.5, though it's by far not the last place in the app that handles connection issues badly.

Comment: It seems network issues are resolved. Balpha, I have posted some UI improvements and suggestions, I would request you to try to check it out. Thanks

Comment: I am sure [These ideas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192406/some-ideas-to-improve-navigation-of-the-android-app) can improve navigation and it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh this answer is posted successfully from Android app.