# Android app should update after successfully posting an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

If I post an answer from the Android app, and it gets posted successfully, then it should show [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192623/149165) and also increment the "answer" counter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed a while back, before version 1.0, thanks!